# Django which is the correct way to store discussion inside db?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I use `django 1.11` with postgresql as the database. I know how to store and retrive data from a db but I can't find an example to which is the correct way to store and to retrieve an entire discussion of two users.

This is my simple idea:
Two users connect to `127.0.0.1` and in this page there is a text-area form. Both users can write into the text-area and by press a button they post their content. The page will reload and now all message are being displayed.

What I want to know is that if the correct way to store and retrive would be:

```
one db row => single message user
```

If two users exchange, say 15 messages, it will store 15 rows and to make a univocal discussion, I can put another column into the db something like discussion "id", so 15 rows would have the same id and the user:

```
db row1 ---> "pk=1, message=hello there, user=Mike, id=45")  
db row2 ---> "pk=2, message=hello world, user=Jessy, id=45")
```

When the page reload clearly in django will run:

```
discussion = Discussion.objects.all().filter(id=45)
```

to retrieve the discussion.

Only two user can discuss in private, so every two user have a discussion page like 127.0.0.1/one, 127.0.0.1/two and so on..

If this is the correct way to store and retrive from the db, my question is how that would scale? Can I rely on that design to store and retrive data from the database efficiently or it will be heavy in near future? I worry that 1000 users could quickly grow into 10000 rows.

Comment: So you'd like to make a chat?

Comment: chat is realtime and I think it's more difficulty to implement in django. I would like to create discussion between two user and the question isn't how do that but if my idea of how store and retrieve the data from the db is the right implementation when I consider also other 1000 users or more. In page1 there is the discussion between Mike and Jimmy, page2 there is the discussion between Luke and Jimmy and so on.

Comment: on average If a discussion contain 20 messages it will store 20 row into the db but if I have 1000 discussion, 1000*20=20000messages=20000row into the db in one day? one hour? so is this the right way to store the discussion into the db?

Comment: 20k rows per day is not that bad. If the discussions will expire after some time, say 7 days, then you can setup a cronjob to run regularly (every morning at 2AM for example) to remove any discussions older than 7 days from your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the answer to your question depends on how you plan on using the data in the future and what you need to do with it. It is entirely possible to store an entire conversation between N users in a columnar database such as Postgres as individual records per message. However, as with all programming questions, there are multiple paradigms to answer your question. I will explore the pros/cons of a couple of them here (with the knowledge that there are certainly more).

**Paradigm 1** New record (row) per message

Pros:

1. Simpler querying for individual *messages*.
2. Analytical functions can easily be applied at a message level (i.e. summing number of messages by certain users)
3. Record size is (relatively) small

Cons:

1. Very long table sizes
2. Searching becomes time consuming as table grows.
3. Post-processing needed on a collection (i.e. All records from a conversation)
4. More work is shifted to the server

**Paradigm 2** New record (row) per conversation

Pros:

1. Simpler querying for individual *conversations*
2. Shorter table sizes
3. Post-processing needed on an object (i.e. The entire conversation stored as a JSON object)

Cons:

1. Larger row size that can grow substantially depending on the number and size of messages.
2. Harder to query individual messages or text within messages (need to use more expensive functions such as LIKE % on blobs of text = slow)
3. Less conducive to preforming any type of analytical function on messages.
4. Messages become an append exercise
5. More work is shifted to the client/application

Which is best? YMMV

Again, there are probably a half-dozen or so more ways you could store your application's messages, and all depend on your downstream needs. Additionally, I would implode you to look into projects such as [Apache Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/) which specialize in message publishing as potentially a scaleable, drop in solution.

Answer (score 1):

Three recommendations:

1. If you give PostgreSQL a decent amount of resources (say, an Amazon m3.large instance), then "a lot of rows" for a PostgreSQL database is around 100 million rows (depending).  That's not a limit, it's just enough rows that you'll have to spend some time working on performance.  So assuming that chats average 100 messages, then that would be one million conversations.  So having one row per message is not a *performance* problem at the scale you're talking about.
2. Don't use a numerical PK as your main way of ordering conversations (you might still have one, Django likes having one).  *Do* have a timestamptz column, which is how you reconstruct the order of conversations.
3. Have a unique index on user, timestamptz (since a user can't post two messages simultaneously), and another unique index on conversation, timestamptz (this will allow you to reconstruct conversations quickly).
4. You should also have a table called "conversations" which summarizes conversation_id, list-of-users, because this will make it easy to answer the request "show me all my conversations".

Does that answer your questions?

Comment: Regarding point 2-3-4: I would like to understand better because when I use form.save() in django than it will generate a row into db with a column named "id (pk serial)" (this id is autoincrement and unique). Sure I will add  timestamptz column, in this way as you say I can order the entire discussion when I reconstruct it but isn't sufficient becuase into the db there are more than one discussion so my idea is to assign also a numerical unique id to each discussion (not PK). In this way I can use:   discussion = Discussion.objects.filter(id_unique_discussion=45).order_by(timestamptz)

Comment: Right, so you want a second, "discussions" entity (table) in the ORM.  You'll create a row in there when a new discussion begins, and update the discussion row with some stats when it ends (for example, total time, list of people, etc.).  The generated ID from the discussion can be re-used in the messages table.